# How to popolate this Dropdown correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown

I'm trying to populate a dropdown menu with jquery with a series of elements (projects) but it doesn't work. From the interface I see the button "dropdown", but if I click it I don't see anything, how can I solve this? When I click it I should see the list of projects that I pass to it (see loop for javascript)

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have added 1 extra curly bracket }

Comment: this time u removed 2 brackets.

Comment: are you trying to pass an id to your **a** tag?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have no way to display the drop down.  There's a comment that says "add [.show] on click" - but you can also do this with hover css, so no need for js.

```
.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}
```

Adding that to your (otherwise working snippet) gives:

```js
var result = {
  "status": 0,
  "message": "OK",
  "projects": ["p1", "p2", "p3"]
}
for (var i = 0; i < result.projects.length; i++) {
  $('#myDropdown').append('<a data-id= "' + i + '">' + result.projects[i] + '</a>');
}
```

```css
.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display:block;
}


.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you *do* want it on click, then you need to add a click handler, eg:

```
$(".dropbtn").click(() => { $(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("show") });
```

Giving:

```js
var result = {
  "status": 0,
  "message": "OK",
  "projects": ["p1", "p2", "p3"]
}
for (var i = 0; i < result.projects.length; i++) {
  $('#myDropdown').append('<a data-id= "' + i + '">' + result.projects[i] + '</a>');
}
$(".dropbtn").click(() => { $(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("show") });
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If they're really `<a>` links then they should have an `<a href=...` to go to the product page.  Otherwise you can add a click handler to `.dropdown-content>a`, get the `.data("id")` value (if using data-id attr) then load your "product" based on that id.  Not nearly enough info in the question to provide details.  Please ask a new question with additional details (don't edit this one).  You can accept this (+upvote...) if it answers your original question here - *how to populate[and show] the drop down menu*.

Comment: they aren't link

Comment: Ok, please ask a new question.

Comment: $(".dropbtn").click(() => { $(".dropdown-content>a"). you have meant like this ? @freedomn-m ?

Comment: @TomBonynge can you see one moment how can I have the control of which voce is benn selected??

Comment: I dont'have the id ==> .data("id") what do you meant?

Comment: `$('#myDropdown').append('<a data-id= "` your question snippet still has `<a=` - if you accept this answer and ask a new question you'll get better response.

Comment: No, as stated above, please ask a new question.  *do not edit your question to change the question after it has been answered*.  Sorry, but that's how SO works.  You ask a question, you get an answer.  If you have a follow on question, you ask a new question (unless it's trivial, which yours is not as explained above - not enough detail on how to "show your product").   Now anyone new coming to your question would see this answer and see that it doesn't answer the (new) question and downvote it.   Is there a reason I'm not aware of that stops you asking a new question?

Comment: User is just new to how SO works.  Hence trying to guide in the right direction.

Comment: Open a new page on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery) and click [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).   I've never asked a question, so not sure if there's a limit that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying.   That's not something I can see.